# Redirection from non-www to www not working Apache2

Tags: python, apache, redirect, flask

I'm trying to follow the first method in this answer https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/42248 to redirect my site *mysite.com* to *www.mysite.com*. The site is using Flask with Python 2.7.6, running on Ubuntu 14.04.

Below is the configuration for it(filename: www.mysite.co.conf):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.co
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/jcapp"
 WSGIDaemonProcess jcapp
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/jcapp/jcapp.wsgi
 <Directory /var/www/jcapp/>
        WSGIProcessGroup jcapp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysite.co
Redirect 301 / http://www.mysite.co/
 WSGIDaemonProcess jcapp
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/jcapp/jcapp.wsgi
 <Directory /var/www/jcapp/>
        WSGIProcessGroup jcapp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After this configuration, I run the following commands:

`sudo a2ensite www.mysite.co.conf`

`sudo service apache2 restart`

I get the following error:

```
Restarting web server apache2                                                                                             
The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next   release /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.mysite.co.conf:1
AH00526: Syntax error on line 27 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.mysite.co.conf:
Name duplicates previous WSGI daemon definition.
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I checked `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and it was empty.

Can someone please tell me what I may be missing out here?

Comment: As the error says, you have duplicate names. Why have you done this in two separate virtual hosts?

Comment: But the `ServerName` in the 2 virtual hosts is different. 

I read in a couple of SO answers about this approach instead of using .htaccess, which by the way wasn't working too and led me to search for an alternative. One such SO answer is linked in the 1st line of the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Plese write the line **redirect permanent / https://site.site.com** in *:80 block of **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf** as shown below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    redirect permanent / https://site.site.com

    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/django_portal/ci/site_portal/portal_site/static
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/django_portal/ci/site_portal/portal_site/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/django_portal/ci/site_portal/portal_site/go_portal_site>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    #WSGIDaemonProcess go_portal_site python-path=/home/ubuntu/django_portal/ci/site_portal/portal_site python-home=/home/ubuntu/django_portal/ci/site_portal/portal_site/phase2_env
    WSGIProcessGroup go_portal_site
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/django_portal/ci/site_portal/portal_site/go_portal_site/wsgi.py
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName site.site.com

    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/django_portal/ci/site_portal/portal_site/static
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/django_portal/ci/site_portal/portal_site/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/django_portal/ci/site_portal/portal_site/go_portal_site>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>


    WSGIDaemonProcess go_portal_site python-path=/home/ubuntu/django_portal/ci/site_portal/portal_site python-home=/home/ubuntu/django_portal/ci/site_portal/portal_site/phase2_env
    WSGIProcessGroup go_portal_site
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/django_portal/ci/site_portal/portal_site/go_portal_site/wsgi.py

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/site.site.com-cer.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/site.site.com-key.pem
```